# QTCreator how to enable password filled option when using Line edit?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, qt-creator

I am new to QT Creator. I have a form that has a line edit and a push button. The line edit has the role to fill in a password. Can anyone please tell me how to enable the property for password to the line edit i have? I would like to see some circles instead of a word when filling in the password.

I am working in c++ under Ubuntu.
THX

Appreciate!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set the echoMode to Password